# Error when updating. Error: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I couldn't figure out how to fix this error:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or 
more required parameters.
```

I get this error whenever I try to update a user's information. I've been trying to figure out what's missing in the code and been searching for a solution. I've found similar questions like this, but it's kind of different because I'm not quite sure which one I should remove.

Here's code:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Geebiz.mdb"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tbl_Student] WHERE [Student_Num] = ?" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_Student] ([Student_Num], [Team_ID], [Team_Status], 
       [Student_University], [Student_UniCountry], [Student_FullName], [Student_PreferredName], 
       [Student_Email], [Student_Email2], [Student_Address1], [Student_Address2],
       [Student_Address3], [Student_AddressCity], [Student_AddressCountry], 
       [Student_AddressPostcode], [Student_MobileCountryList], [Student_MobilePhone],
       [Student_Facebook], [Student_Skype], [Student_Gender], [Student_CourseRep], 
       [Student_English], [Student_Broadband], [Student_CompAccess], [Recommender_Name], 
       [Recommender_Email], [Recommender_Phone], [Student_Status]) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_Student] WHERE ([Student_Num] = ?)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_Student] SET [Team_ID] = ?, [Team_Status] = ?, 
    [Student_University] = ?, [Student_UniCountry] = ?, [Student_FullName] = ?, 
    [Student_PreferredName] = ?, [Student_Email] = ?, [Student_Email2] = ?, 
    [Student_Address1] = ?, [Student_Address2] = ?, [Student_Address3] = ?, 
    [Student_AddressCity] = ?, [Student_AddressCountry] = ?, [Student_AddressPostcode] = ?, 
    [Student_MobilePhoneCountryCode] = ?, [Student_MobileCountryList] = ?, [Student_Facebook] = 
    ?, [Student_Skype] = ?, [Student_Gender] = ?, [Student_CourseRep] = ?, [Student_English] = ?,
    [Student_Broadband] = ?, [Student_CompAccess] = ?, [Recommender_Name] = ?, 
    [Recommender_Email] = ?, [Recommender_Phone] = ?, [Student_Status] = ? 
    WHERE [Student_Num] = ?">

    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Student_Num"
           PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <DeleteParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Num" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
```

I think the error is somewhere around here:

```
  <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Team_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Team_Status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_University" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_UniCountry" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_FullName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_PreferredName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Email2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Address1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Address2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Address3" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_AddressCity" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_AddressCountry" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_AddressPostcode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_MobileCountryList" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_MobilePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Facebook" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Skype" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_CourseRep" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_English" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Broadband" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_CompAccess" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recommender_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recommender_Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recommender_Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Num" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>

        <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Num" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Team_ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Team_Status" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_University" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_UniCountry" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_FullName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_PreferredName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Email2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Address1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Address2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Address3" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_AddressCity" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_AddressCountry" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_AddressPostcode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_MobileCountryList" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_MobilePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Facebook" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Skype" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_CourseRep" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_English" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Broadband" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_CompAccess" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recommender_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recommender_Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recommender_Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Student_Status" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>

<asp:Label ID="lbl_message2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black">
   Please select a student from the left column first, before you click the 
   continue button in order to update the student detail.
</asp:Label><br />
<asp:Button ID="btn_continue" runat="server" Text="Continue" /><br /><br />
The detail of the student you have selected is shown below:<br />
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
   DataKeyNames="Student_Num" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" Height="32px" Width="536px">

<Fields>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Num" HeaderText="Student_Num" InsertVisible="False"
ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Student_Num" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Team_ID" HeaderText="Team_ID" SortExpression="Team_ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Team_Status" HeaderText="Team_Status" SortExpression="Team_Status" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_University" HeaderText="Student_University"
   SortExpression="Student_University" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_UniCountry" HeaderText="Student_UniCountry" 
   SortExpression="Student_UniCountry" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_FullName" HeaderText="Student_FullName" 
   SortExpression="Student_FullName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_PreferredName" HeaderText="Student_PreferredName"
SortExpression="Student_PreferredName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Email" HeaderText="Student_Email"
   SortExpression="Student_Email" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Email2" HeaderText="Student_Email2" 
     SortExpression="Student_Email2" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Address1" HeaderText="Student_Address1" 
    SortExpression="Student_Address1" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Address2" HeaderText="Student_Address2" 
     SortExpression="Student_Address2" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Address3" HeaderText="Student_Address3" 
     SortExpression="Student_Address3" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_AddressCity" HeaderText="Student_AddressCity"
SortExpression="Student_AddressCity" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_AddressCountry" HeaderText="Student_AddressCountry"
SortExpression="Student_AddressCountry" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_AddressPostcode" HeaderText="Student_AddressPostcode"
SortExpression="Student_AddressPostcode" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_MobileCountryList" HeaderText="Student_MobileCountryList"
     SortExpression="Student_MobileCountryList" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_MobilePhone" HeaderText="Student_MobilePhone" 
     SortExpression="Student_MobilePhone" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Facebook" HeaderText="Student_Facebook" 
     SortExpression="Student_Facebook" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Skype" HeaderText="Student_Skype" 
     SortExpression="Student_Skype" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Gender" HeaderText="Student_Gender" 
     SortExpression="Student_Gender" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_CourseRep" HeaderText="Student_CourseRep" 
     SortExpression="Student_CourseRep" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_English" HeaderText="Student_English" 
     SortExpression="Student_English" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Broadband" HeaderText="Student_Broadband" 
     SortExpression="Student_Broadband" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_CompAccess" HeaderText="Student_CompAccess" 
     SortExpression="Student_CompAccess" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Recommender_Name" HeaderText="Recommender_Name" 
     SortExpression="Recommender_Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Recommender_Email" HeaderText="Recommender_Email" 
     SortExpression="Recommender_Email" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Recommender_Phone" HeaderText="Recommender_Phone" 
     SortExpression="Recommender_Phone" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Student_Status" HeaderText="Student_Status" 
     SortExpression="Student_Status" />
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Check to make sure that some of the fields that could end up option in the access database allow empty values. If you don't allow an empty value to be entered in Access, it's going to throw an error like this if a user doesn't put information in that field. Example: User doesn't have a Skype account but the Access field doesn't allow empty values so it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameter in the UpdateCommand should be same as in the UpdateParameters. Also, check your `[Student_MobilePhoneCountryCode]` is missing from the UpdateParameter list.